# Unable to deploy to EB using Bitbucket pipelines

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

We have established pipelines scripts that work very well. Lately, we decided to deploy to elastic beanstalk automatically, with the use of bitbucket pipelines and following the tutorial which uses the command `eb deploy` to deploy. Apparently, this command fails on pipelines. The config files seem legit because it runs locally. It also runs from inside a container of the same image that we have specified in the pipelines file and also by using docker exec from the local to run the command inside a container of the same image. The following are the pipelines file and the error we get using `eb deploy --verbose` command. I am obviously missing something here. Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

```html
feature/KKLT-1065-deploy-via-pipelines:
  - step:
      deployment: staging
      caches:
        - composer
      script:
        - php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
        - cat .env
        - composer install
        - php artisan cache:clear
        - php artisan migrate
        - php artisan db:seed
        - eb init KMLT-staging-ttl -r eu-central-1 -p "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v2.6.4 running PHP 7.1"
        - eb deploy --verbose
      services:
        - postgres
```

```html
+ eb deploy --verbose
INFO: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebrun.py", line 41, in run_app
    app.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 475, in _dispatch
    self._parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 452, in _parse_args
    self.app._parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 1076, in _parse_args
    for res in self.hook.run('post_argument_parsing', self):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/core/hook.py", line 150, in run
    res = hook[2](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/hooks.py", line 35, in pre_run_hook
    set_profile(app.pargs.profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/core/hooks.py", line 47, in set_profile
    profile = commonops.get_default_profile()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/commonops.py", line 973, in get_default_profile
    profile = get_config_setting_from_branch_or_default('profile')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/commonops.py", line 1008, in get_config_setting_from_branch_or_default
    setting = get_setting_from_current_branch(key_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/operations/commonops.py", line 991, in get_setting_from_current_branch
    branch_name = source_control.get_current_branch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/objects/sourcecontrol.py", line 184, in get_current_branch
    stdout, stderr, exitcode = self._run_cmd(revparse_command, handle_exitcode=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ebcli/objects/sourcecontrol.py", line 480, in _run_cmd
    stdout, stderr, exitcode = exec_cmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cement/utils/shell.py", line 40, in exec_cmd
    proc = Popen(cmd_args, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
INFO: OSError - [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you determine the version of `eb` running on the machine where the failure occurred? Also, can you rerun the `eb deploy` command with the `--debug` flag instead of `--verbose`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try python3 version of eb instead of python2.7. Might have more success.

Comment: That did it. Wow it really worked, thanks. I don't know why it worked on local and on docker images using python2.7. Strange.